# What does the symbol =?= mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, comparison-operators

Can somebody offer some insight into what this symbol means and how it is used in Scala?  I first saw this symbol in this video about Functional Structure in Scala (You can see him typing the symbol here: https://youtu.be/tD_EyIKqqCk?t=3364)

A google search came up with this link to an outdated HTCondor manual in section 4.1.3.3 / Comparison operators / point 5 (https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.8/4_1HTCondor_s_ClassAd.html#ClassAd:evaluation-meta)

It states:
"In addition, the operators =?= and =!= behave similar to == and !=, but are not strict. Semantically, the =?= tests if its operands are `identical,'' i.e., have the same type and the same value. For example, 10 == UNDEFINED and UNDEFINED == UNDEFINED both evaluate to UNDEFINED, but 10 =?= UNDEFINED and UNDEFINED =?= UNDEFINED evaluate to FALSE and TRUE respectively. The =!= operator test for the` is not identical to'' condition."

My question is, would using '==' give the same results in the code shown?

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-do-i-find-what-some-symbol-means-or-does). - TL;DR; no idea what that symbol is, it can be mean anything since it is not part of the language, without mentioning from which library it is coming is impossible to know what it means.

Comment: I think it is a function defined in `Equals.scala` file by the video author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote you have is from some language ClassAd that does not seem to be related to Scala. I've never seen that method `=?=` before.

However, I found the definition of it [here](https://github.com/prurph/fsis-scala/blob/1276b95c5c2babfdf0a5600f817d1fab4214df89/src/main/scala/Equals.scala#L39), in a repository owned by Michael Pilquist, who also made the video:

```
object IsEq {
  implicit class Syntax[A](lhs: A) {
    def =?=(rhs: A): IsEq[A] = IsEq(lhs, rhs)
  }
}
```

`IsEq` is defined as such:

```
case class IsEq[A](lhs: A, rhs: A) {
  def isEqual(implicit eq: Equal[A]): Boolean = eq.isEqual(lhs, rhs)
}
```

And `Equal` seems to be a typeclass for restricting equality to objects of the same type and using custom behavior for comparison (e.g. there is an `Equal` instance for `List` that checks all the elements are equal).

```
trait Equal[A] {
  def isEqual(lhs: A, rhs: A): Boolean
}
```

Comment: Thank you user, you are a mystery, but your answer is not, its clarifying.